# Jquery fade-Slideshow buggs in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, fadein

I've got a little problem with my very tiny "slideshow" script.

```
$(function(){
$('#slider img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
$('#slider :first-child').fadeOut('slow').next('img').fadeIn('slow').end().appendTo('#slider');}, 5000);});
```

The problem is:

in IE on win8 everything is okay.. (InternetExplorer works O.O ?)
but on Firefox it's sometimes buggy like the picture suddenly appears without fade or appears just the half size of the image...

What could it be?
demo page:
http://jsfiddle.net/arL3nawm/
mytestserver.square7.ch (could take a little time until it's up..)

Comment: You're right :)

http://jsfiddle.net/arL3nawm/

But it seems to load okay on fiddle. Maybe because the image width isn't as big as 100% to a 1920x1200 screen :(

Edit: Okay it's a little buggy too :) I hope you can see it

Comment: yeah it working okay on fiddle y not use css

Comment: you mean no js ?

Is there a good tutorial? I'm not well with CSS3 and HTML5 for now

Comment: this http://css.dzone.com/articles/css3-fade-slider might help and also save you some security issues

Comment: sounds nice but it doesn't work on IE :(